# Child browser plugin vs navigator.app.loadurl

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to know what is major difference between Childbrowser plugin and navigator.app.loadurl. There is any performance variance among these two?

To my understanding the Childbrowser plugin is native for both IOS and android. Anything else

Childbrowser:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.google.com", { showLocationBar: false });
```

Navigator:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl('http://www.google.com', { openExternal:true } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ChildBrowser plugin allows you a bit more fine grained control of the browser. For instance you get events when the location changes in the child browser which is useful for doing things like oauth.

Other than that the code is nearly identical on Android which is the only platform that supports navigator.app.loadUrl().

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<a href="#" onclick="openUrlInBlankBrowser();" target="_system"  >Link</a>

function openUrlInBlankBrowser()
{
    navigator.app.loadUrl('http://www.google.com', { openExternal:true } ); 
}
```